# Automatic install of software in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, automated-install

I have to install many user's computer with WinXP and some useful software. It's a bit boring to click on "Next" and "Yes" each time I install something.

- Is there any script (or command line) that allows me to install software and automatically answer "Yes" and "Next" to all questions?
- Can I install everything without prompting "setup windows"?

It would make my work eaiser and faster.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [Software to force installer/setup to run silently?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/21638/3474)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WPKG](http://wpkg.org) makes for an excellent way of installing software. You can't just auto-click next, but its flexible enough to allow you to run msiexec for your silent install msi files as well as custom commands for whatever else you run.

Answer (score 3):

[AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/) is fantastic, there are others but i've set up many auto-installs with this.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.appdeploy.com/

has information about application deploy, not all the software are in the list, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off setting up one machine, taking an image of it and deploying that image. There are numerous ways to do this. It's not practical to write a tutorial here but fortunately a lot of other people have already written them. A bit of Googling should turn up plenty of articles on the various deployment methods.

Comment: I agree it's a useful technique, but it only works when all machines have the same hardware (or at the very least the same mainboard). Otherwise XP might not work at all.

Comment: True, although I've personally never had a problem doing this. At worst I've had to update the drivers afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

u can  use [nilte](http://www.nliteos.com/) to customise instalation of winxp;
and add all sort of software by this "www.winaddons.com"
There is option of unattended install.